# How to do i Get only Double Quotes String by using php

Tags: php, string

How to do I get all strings enclosed in a pair of double-quotes by using php, I want to get them in the following string,

```
$str = 'a:2:{i:1;a:4:{i:1;s:4:"2000";i:2;s:8:"10th STD";i:3;s:9:"Full Time";i:4;s:24:"State Board of Education";}i:2;a:4:{i:1;s:4:"2003";i:2;s:8:"12th STD";i:3;s:9:"Full Time";i:4;s:24:"State Board of Education";}}';
```

**I want output as follows**

```
2000
10th STD
Full Time
State Board of Education
```

I tried the following code but output comes only `2000`

```
<?php

$str = 'a:2:{i:1;a:4:{i:1;s:4:"2000";i:2;s:8:"10th STD";i:3;s:9:"Full Time";i:4;s:24:"State Board of Education";}i:2;a:4:{i:1;s:4:"2003";i:2;s:8:"12th STD";i:3;s:9:"Full Time";i:4;s:24:"State Board of Education";}}'

if (preg_match('/"([^"]+)"/', $str, $m)) 
{
print $m[1];   
} 
else 
{

}
<?
```

Please suggest me how to do it, which function should I used to get my output?

Comment: That looks like a *PHP serialized* array. Use `unserialize()` to unserialize it, then treat it as array. Don't even start with using regular expressions here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hope this will help u.

```
<?php
        $str = 'a:2:{i:1;a:4:{i:1;s:4:"2000";i:2;s:8:"10th STD";i:3;s:9:"Full Time";i:4;s:24:"State Board of Education";}i:2;a:4:{i:1;s:4:"2003";i:2;s:8:"12th STD";i:3;s:9:"Full Time";i:4;s:24:"State Board of Education";}}';

        $str_array = unserialize($str);  
        foreach($str_array as $values) {
            foreach($values as $value) {
                echo $value . '<br/>';
            }
            echo '<br/>';
        }
?>
```

will return:

2000
10th STD
Full Time
State Board of Education

2003
12th STD
Full Time
State Board of Education

Comment: i need to print the above output like <tr> <td>2000</td> <td>10th STD</td><td>Full Time</td><td>State Board</td> <tr> How to do i split like row value?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bog standard serialized array, so just apply unserialize() on the string, then parse through the values and apply is_string on them, and you'll achieve the result in a clean way.

Answer (score 1):

As said above, unserialize() then convert to string

```
<?php
    $str = 'a:2:{i:1;a:4:{i:1;s:4:"2000";i:2;s:8:"10th STD";i:3;s:9:"Full Time";i:4;s:24:"State Board of Education";}i:2;a:4:{i:1;s:4:"2003";i:2;s:8:"12th STD";i:3;s:9:"Full Time";i:4;s:24:"State Board of Education";}}';
    $str=unserialize($str);
    $str2=implode("<br>",$str[1]);
    print $str2."\n";
?>
```

Gives

```
2000<br>10th STD<br>Full Time<br>State Board of Education
```

Comment: I want to display like Year is column and column value should be 2000 and Class is Column and Class value STD like this i want to display. can u give any idea for this